# Can someone explain to me this recursive code for binary tree?

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to solve this problem "Binary tree upside down". For example, if we have a binary tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 / \
4   5
```

After running my function, it will become:

```
   4
  / \
 5   2
    / \
   3   1
```

I got the following recursive code, but cannot understand the steps between //1 and //5;

```
public TreeNode UpsideDownBinaryTree(TreeNode root)
{
    if (root == null) return null;

    TreeNode parent = root, left = root.left, right = root.right;
    if (left != null)
    {
        TreeNode ret = UpsideDownBinaryTree(left); //1
        left.left = right;   //2
        left.right = parent; //3
        return ret;          //4
    }
    return root;             //5
}
```

Can someone explain to me in details what each step is doing here? Also, why do we have two separate returns: `return ret`, `return root`?

I know how to do recursion for regular arrays, lists and some binary trees. But this recursion logic seems different from what I knew before. I even used IDE to step through, but still cannot fully understand it.

I also have the following iterative code for this question. I can understand this code. It scans the tree from root to leave. But for the recursive code, it's scanning the tree from root to leave and building the new tree from leave to root? Am I understanding it correctly?

```
public TreeNode UpSideDownTree_Iterative(TreeNode root)
    {
        TreeNode node = root,parent = null,right = null;
        while (node != null) {
            TreeNode left = node.left;
            node.left = right;
            right = node.right;
            node.right = parent;
            parent = node;
            node = left;
        }
        return parent;
}
```

Comment: Recursive functional explanation in binary tree: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863538/recursive-functional-explanation-in-binary-tree?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to look at it from the last invocation backwards.
The method is recursively invoked with left node, so it will be invoked with nodes 1,2 and 4. 
Last left node (leaf) is node 4 : 
See comments:

```
//when invoked with node 4 
public TreeNode UpsideDownBinaryTree(TreeNode root)
{
    if (root == null) return null;

    TreeNode parent = root;      //node 4 
    TreeNode leftNode = root.left;   //null  
    TreeNode rightNode = root.right; //null  

    if (leftNode != null) 
    {
        //not executed
        TreeNode ret = UpsideDownBinaryTree(leftNode); //invoke with 2
        leftNode.left = rightNode; //left of node 2 becomes node 3
        leftNode.right = parent; //right of node 2 becomes 1
        return ret;          
    }
    return root;             //returned. The leaf becomes new root
}
```

Let's look at the previous step : it returns to the previous invocation (node 2) :

```
//when invoked with node 2 
public TreeNode UpsideDownBinaryTree(TreeNode root)
{
    if (root == null) return null;

    TreeNode parent = root;       //node 2 
    TreeNode leftNode = root.left;   //node 4  
    TreeNode rightNode = root.right; //node 5 

    if (leftNode != null) 
    {
        TreeNode ret = UpsideDownBinaryTree(leftNode); //invoke with node 4
                                                       //as seen above return 
                                                       //value is node 4 
                                                       //which is the new root
        leftNode.left = rightNode; //left of node 4 becomes node 5
        leftNode.right = parent; //right of node 4 becomes 2
        return ret; //node 4 returned, the new root        
    }
    return root;            
}
```

The first invocation (node 1), is very similar to node 2.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's very helpful, and I think I understand it better. Is there any other recursive ways to implement this function? I just wanted to do some comparison in order to understand it better.

Comment: Please post other question (" Is there any other recursive ways to implement this function?" ) in a separate post. It may be more appropriate here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/